# How do I do file io in J?

Tags: tacit-programming, j

I want to be able to read and write files, etc. How can I do this?

Comment: Ops, I wrote an answer for Java :D Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Chapter 28: Data Files](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/28.htm) of [Learning J](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/contents.htm#toc).

I found several other learning resources on J Software's [Getting Started](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Guides/Getting%20Started) page.

Comment: They say to do this in the link Bill provided, but it's important to remember that a filename needs to be boxed before you can use it to import data in J. The first few times I tried file I/O, I had to re-discover that fact after an extended period of fussing.

Comment: Using the `files` library is usually the best workaround to avoid having to remember such nasty little requirements.